# Test client code for full duplex mode

Tags: c

I implemented C network client using LWIP library on a small controller board. How I can I test it is it full full duplex mode or not?

Is there any simple test tool or some other way?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is incredibly vague, but I'm taking a punt and saying you're developing a TCP/IP client.

If so, [Hercules](http://www.hw-group.com/products/hercules/index_en.html) is a brilliant tool for Windows. If you're on Linux, you can just use `netcat`.